# Electron - Load session with session.fromPartition() but without modifying partition while using browser

Tags: electron

Here is how I create the original partition where I login with my google account :
`const ses = session.fromPartition("persist:profile_1")`
On this instance I login my google accout.
*After restarting application*
**Here come my problem:**
if I load created partition `profile_1`
Like that : `const ses = session.fromPartition("persist:profile_1")`
=> It will save session in partition,  **but I WON'T**, what I want is to use the original partition every time I need its google accout but without saving all navigation information
AND, if I load created partition `profile_1`
Like that : `const ses = session.fromPartition("profile_1")`
The partition isn't loaded and I'm not connected to my google account

*Sorry if it's not clear english isn't my native language, please ask question if you don't see what I'm clearly talking about :)*

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative, **duplicate** the original partition.

```
function clonePartition(partitionName, newPartionName) {

    var pathToOriginal = process.env.APPDATA + "\\AppName\\Partitions\\" + partitionName
    var pathToCopy     = process.env.APPDATA + "\\AppName\\Partitions\\" + newPartionName

    fs.copy(pathToOriginal, pathToCopy);
}
```

You are now able to load the newPartition :
`const ses = session.fromPartition("persist:newPartionName")`